# Showing OSD 0 after installing rook-ceph in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, rook-storage, kubernetes-rook

I have set up 3 node kubernetes using 3 VPS and installed rook/ceph.

when I run

```
kubectl exec -it rook-ceph-tools-78cdfd976c-6fdct -n rook-ceph bash
ceph status
```

I get the below result

```
osd: 0 osds: 0 up, 0 in
```

I tried

```
ceph device ls
```

and the result is

```
DEVICE  HOST:DEV  DAEMONS  LIFE EXPECTANCY
```

`ceph osd status` gives me no result

This is the yaml file that I used

```
https://github.com/rook/rook/blob/master/cluster/examples/kubernetes/ceph/cluster.yaml
```

When I use the below command

```
sudo kubectl -n rook-ceph logs rook-ceph-osd-prepare-node1-4xddh provision
```

results are

```
2021-05-10 05:45:09.440650 I | cephosd: skipping device "sda1" because it contains a filesystem "ext4"
2021-05-10 05:45:09.440653 I | cephosd: skipping device "sda2" because it contains a filesystem "ext4"
2021-05-10 05:45:09.475841 I | cephosd: configuring osd devices: {"Entries":{}}
2021-05-10 05:45:09.475875 I | cephosd: no new devices to configure. returning devices already configured with ceph-volume.
2021-05-10 05:45:09.476221 D | exec: Running command: stdbuf -oL ceph-volume --log-path /tmp/ceph-log lvm list  --format json
2021-05-10 05:45:10.057411 D | cephosd: {}
2021-05-10 05:45:10.057469 I | cephosd: 0 ceph-volume lvm osd devices configured on this node
2021-05-10 05:45:10.057501 D | exec: Running command: stdbuf -oL ceph-volume --log-path /tmp/ceph-log raw list --format json
2021-05-10 05:45:10.541968 D | cephosd: {}
2021-05-10 05:45:10.551033 I | cephosd: 0 ceph-volume raw osd devices configured on this node
2021-05-10 05:45:10.551274 W | cephosd: skipping OSD configuration as no devices matched the storage settings for this node "node1"
```

My disk partition

```
root@node1: lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   400G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   953M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 399.1G  0 part /
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem that OSD doesn't appear in `ceph status`, after I install and teardown for test multiple times.

I fixed this issue by running

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M status=progress
```

to completely remove any information on such raw block disk.

Comment: can you pls. elaborate the command in bit more detail.

Comment: @Sanjeev - the theory is to completely clean up the disk and re-let `ceph` populate on a new disk

Answer (score 1):

I guess for roof ceph to work I should attach an additional raw volume to my nodes, since it does not allow directories mounted on the main disk.

It looks like this now

```
root@node1:~/marketing-automation-agency# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   400G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   953M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 399.1G  0 part /
```

Comment: Yes indeed you need a raw disk call it as sdb. Otherwise Ceph wont work at all.      
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0     0      32G  0 disk
|-sda1              8:1     0    600M  0 part /boot/efi
|-sda2             8:2     0         1G  0 part /boot
`-sda3            8:3     0   30.4G  0 part
  |-rhel-root 253:0    0    27.2G  0 lvm  /
  `-rhel-swap 253:1    0   3.2G  0 lvm
sdb             8:16   0         100G  0 disk

Comment: This was created by me, please see once https://github.com/rook/rook/issues/11153